# UICollectionView crash on unhighlightAllItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I've gotten several crash reports related to a UICollectionView in iOS 7.  I'm not able to consistently recreate this crash.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x91c4392b
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '', reason: ''

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39dd2b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                               0x31fd5eef -[UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 111
2   UIKit                               0x32060bfd -[UICollectionView _unhighlightItemAtIndexPath:animated:notifyDelegate:] + 149
3   UIKit                               0x32383947 -[UICollectionView _unhighlightAllItems] + 151
4   UIKit                               0x3205f9fb -[UICollectionView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 367
5   UIKit                               0x31fcb101 forwardTouchMethod + 233
6   UIKit                               0x31fcb101 forwardTouchMethod + 233
7   UIKit                               0x31e3be4b _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5523
8   UIKit                               0x31e73c41 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 773
9   UIKit                               0x31e735e7 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
10  UIKit                               0x31e48a25 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 197
11  UIKit                               0x31e47221 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7097
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2f69e18b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2f69d6e1 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 341
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2f69be4f __CFRunLoopRun + 623
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2f606ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2f606acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
17  GraphicsServices                    0x342f4283 GSEventRunModal + 139
18  UIKit                               0x31ea8a41 UIApplicationMain + 1137
19  JackThreadsIpad                     0x000922b7 main (main.m:16)
```

The UICollectionViewCells in the app share a common superclass that manages highlighting.  When the cell is highlighted the alpha changes.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (highlighted) {
        self.alpha = 0.8;
    } else {
        self.alpha = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Could calling [super setHighlighted:highlighted] cause a crash like this?  The app was compiled and submitted with XCode 4 and is only happening on iOS 7.  Any other suggestions to figure out where this is happening.  Thanks for your help.

Edit:
I was able to catch this in the debugger, but it still is not consistently reproducible.  The crash is:

```
[NSIndexPath section] message sent to deallocated instance XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Have you added break points in setHighlighted and cellForItemAtIndexPath? What happens when you step through,  where does it crash.

Comment: I have not seen this crash in my development environment- this and similar crash reports came in through iTunes Connect and Crittercism

Comment: Sorry I missed the line where you said you can't reproduce it

Comment: I am seeing this crash as well, and I can reproduce it. It seems to be related to if you override setHighlighted in your cells and then call reloadData repeatedly on the UICollectionView, but I still haven't found a workaround. Does not happen in iOS 6.

Comment: Getting the exact same crash. Happens when scrolling very very fast in my collection view. It does not seem to be related to highlighted, as I am not overriding any highlight methods.

Comment: I assume you have added an `exception breakpoint` to catch `All Exceptions`.

Comment: I also see `reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0xd84fc10> was mutated while being enumerated.'` when this crash happens. It's failing on `unhighlightAllItems` but I am doing no custom highlighting.

Comment: Don't suppose anyone ever found a solution to this? I'm having the exact same crash, and can't find a way to stop it!

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling reloadData while the user is dragging the view, that might be the reason.

I had crashes related to this with similar crash reports and "fixed" the issue by delaying the reloadData call until after the user has finished scrolling the view. E.g. create a wrapped method instead of calling reloadData directly.

```
- (void)updateData {
     if (self.collectionView.isTracking) {
         self.updateDataOnScrollingEnded = YES;
     } else {
         [self.collectionView reloadData];
     }
}
```

Then when scrolling ends, call the updateData method (if needed) from the scroll view's delegate methods.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        [self scrollViewStopped:scrollView];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollViewStopped:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewStopped:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.updateDataOnScrollingEnded) {
         [self updateData];
         self.updateDataOnScrollingEnded = NO;
     }
}
```

My guess is that there is a weak reference to the highlighted cell's indexPath somewhere inside of the collectionView, and that calling reload will dealloc that indexPath. When the collectionView then tries to unhighlight the cell, it crashes.

EDIT:

As mentioned in comments below, this "solution" has some flaws. While investigating the issue further, it seems that in my case the problem had to do with multiple reloadData calls being queued on the main thread during the dragging of the collection view. When there was only one reloadData call, everything was fine, but whenever there was more than one – crash!

Since I always had exactly one section in my collectionView i replaced the reloadData call with

```
reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
```

However, this causes the cells to quickly fade out and back in again which I avoided with the following method (it would probably be better off as a category on the collection view)

```
- (void)reloadCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:animated];
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    }];
}
```

So far, this has worked well for me and it also allows for the data to actually be updated while scrolling.

Comment: I think this nails the problem... when the collection view starts to track, it will highlight a cell, but when reloadData is called, it appears the highlighted status gets retained even when tracking stops.  At that point, sometime in the future, the old highlighted index path will cause the crash.  Unfortunately for your solution, tracking can start and stop without dragging ever starting, which means you will never get any callbacks to actually call reloadData (and since the start of dragging usually un-highlights the cells, it's probably not an issue when isDragging is YES).

Comment: Another thing to note about the solution; make sure all the delegate and data source methods are prepared to accept NSIndexPaths relating to the old data until -reloadData is actually called.  Those can certainly be invoked during dragging and scrolling, and without the -reloadData, the collection view will still be basing its calls on the previous data.

Comment: Good points! Since I posted the answer I've discovered that calling reloadData on a collectionView a second time (before it has had the chance to reload the data the first time) seemed to be the real issue. The reloadSections method did not have this problem and since the app I developed always had one section with at least one cell, I switched to use reloadSections instead.

Comment: Hmmm.  I tried that solution, and some variants, in a test app and I can still make it crash, though it often shows up as mutating a set during enumeration instead of a freed object issue.  I'm not sure how one reload could start before the other finishes (unless they are on separate threads, which would be bad)... it should be a synchronous call.  If I call the private method _unhighlightAllItems (seen in the backtrace above) before the reloadData everything is OK but that's not really a viable approach.  Still kinda stumped.

Comment: I'm now thinking if you delay the reloadData if isTracking is on, and then call it (if delayed) in collectionView:didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:, that might do the trick.  Unhighlight is called if the user lets up without starting a dragging session, or if they start to drag (in which case touchesCancelled: gets called on the collection view, and it unhighlights while panning).  The caveat about not installing the data on the dataSource until reloadData is actually called still applies.  (unsure which index paths didSelect: would use after the unhighlight when just letting go.)

Comment: Just to note, I think the issue was some internal UICollectionView state tracking highlighted items which was not reset if -reloadData was called while isTracking.  If you can find a way to clear those, it might help, though public API is lacking (there are some private API calls which work, but... not helpful for App Store submissions).  It looks like Apple fixed the bug in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure after identifying only this piece of code. But as crash signal (SIGSEGV) seems due to memory leak. You just go to your Xcode setting and inside Edit Scheme jsut enable Zombie option and then try to reproduce your crash. It will show you the controller class name of method or any crash related information inside console of Xcode.
And also just try to modify you condition below:-

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {

     //just comment this line or write this line to the below and check
     //[super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    if (highlighted) {
        self.alpha = 0.8;
    } else {
        self.alpha = 1.0;
    }
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, though slightly different crash.  Fixed by holding off any reloadData until the highlight is cleared.  While toostn's suggestion would fix the issue, it is useful to be able to reloadData whilst scrolling, but doesn't make much sense when highlighting - as you have your finger on a cell.

implement the following UICollectionViewDelegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.allowReload = NO;
    return YES;
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.allowReload = YES;
    [self reloadIfNecessary]; // calls reloadData if it is necessary to do so!
}
```

Comment: I think that this answer gets closer to the root of the problem.  I verified that if I return NO from shouldHighlight then I no longer get the crash.  I still don't exactly understand where the reloadData comes into play, but it's as if there are unhighlight calls being deferred prior to touch began and if I call reloadData between the time the highlight started and ended AND if I'm scrolling fast enough such that the cell is off screen (and presumably dealloc'd?) then I get this crash.  Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Edit: Spoke too soon.  Oddly, I still get the crash ripping out of unhighlight even if I return NO from shouldHighlight...  Also, deferring the reload to after didUnhighlightItem results in the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this crash in `_unhighlightAllItems` in a collection view where I used a long press recognizer that changes the state of cells (but not their number) and then called `[collectionView reloadData]`. In my case, the solution from @toostn (using `performBatchUpdates`) works great.

I also found that using `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` instead of `reloadData` also avoids the crash.